# How to install the real Firefox on Debian?

Tags: linux, firefox, debian

[Debian 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Timeline) ("Squeeze") uses a rebranded version of Firefox called [Iceweasel](http://packages.debian.org/sid/iceweasel). It, however, lacks plugin support, and most of my favorites don't work.

So what is best way to install the "real" Firefox on Debian?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

First, you need to remove the existing Iceweasel package (I think you can use `aptitude` as well):

```
apt-get remove iceweasel
```

Then, download [the latest Linux build of Firefox directly from Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/).  Extract the files, and navigate to that folder, and run it.  If you want, make an icon on your desktop, and you can also make a link to the binary in `/usr/bin/firefox` to make it easier to launch.  If you have root access, you can also [install Firefox in `/usr/local`](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Install-and-Update/Install-Firefox-on-Linux/ta-p/2516) so all users will be able to run it.

After this, double-check that automatic updates are enabled, and you should be up and running!

---

If you want a package-based one, you can use [Linux Mint's Debian package repo](http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Debian) (as noted in the comments below, be aware that this may cause conflicts with automatic updates and other Debian packages [in some cases](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=119719)).  To do this, add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import
```

And [add the GPG key](https://thestandardoutput.com/2013/06/install-the-real-firefox-on-debian-7/) for that repo.
Then, just run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install firefox
```

And you should be good to go!

The default install is German, to install in any other language, you can manually run:

```
apt-get install firefox-l10n-en-us 

(Edit[11/26/2014]: This package no longer appears in the linux mint repository.)
(Edit[11/26/2014]: apt-get install firefox-l10n-en-gb - This is the only working English package)
```

Packages names for other common langages include ([official repository list](http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Debian) - scroll half way down):

```
 firefox-l10n-en-gb       # British English
 firefox-l10n-es          # Spanish
 firefox-l10n-fr          # French
 firefox-l10n-de          # German
```

Comment: Definitely easier than what I suggested.

Comment: Bah, got no notification that you were writing -- beat me to it :P

Comment: What about GPG signature of that repository?

Comment: Done that. It's Dutch language version- any ideas how to make it English?

Comment: @nodiscc that's the default repository included with Debian to begin with... If you look at the linked repository in that answer, it only has Iceweasel, not Firefox (as the OP requested).  If you are really against using another popular Linux distribution's repository, you might want to consider adding the [Daily-Built Ubuntu Firefox/Thunderbird PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa).

Comment: This really is a testament to the beauty of Debian ... there's many ways to tweak your build ... I ♥ Debian ... ;-)

Comment: Might want to just get rid of the version number - it changes so fast now.

Comment: Where can I verify the GPG signature of the package?

Comment: Ad GPG: downloading and manually (`dpkg -i`) installing `linuxmint-keyring_*.deb` from [Mint's repo](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/l/linuxmint-keyring/) (before installing any package from actual repo) worked for me (Wheezy).

Comment: For those missing the icon, google "mozicon128.png" and save it as /usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png

Comment: @JustinSane The icon can be also found somewhere under /opt/firefox, so you can simply copy it ... or fix all .desktop files to point to the /opt/... path (in case you don't have permissions).

Comment: I never recommend this solution. In fact adding such repository (although it is based on the same distro) can cause conflict in dependencies. This method works for installing and updating firefox, but it does make some conflicts with other packages. If you need the firefox, you just get the code and extract it in your `/opt/` and create a global link to it.

Comment: @Breakthrough How to subsequently update this install?I tried to install to FF33.0 from FF30.0 and lost my installed addons.

Comment: E: Package 'firefox' has no installation candidate

Comment: Be aware! (http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=119719) Don't mix Debian with Mint.

Comment: @emab That's what I did, it's easier than track packages. I don't know if the libraries involved are from debian repos or mint ones... this detail is the key. Arguing that every other package will be found on original repos, you can add it, install firefox then remove the ppa later. Otherwise the best option is to use /opt.

Comment: @Dr Mint is built from Ubuntu, and Ubuntu from Debian. It's really a bad idea to mix them :D

Answer (score 35):

There's a sourcefourge project, basically dedicated to allowing you to get the latest version of Firefox when running Ubuntu, no matter which version you run (as long as dependencies are satisfied, obviously). Since Ubuntu is a Debian derivative, I thought I'd try it. I've got Firefox working on Debian Testing ("Wheezy") just fine.

Run this:

```
apt-get remove iceweasel
echo -e "\ndeb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29
apt-get update
apt-get install firefox-mozilla-build
```

This resolves the GPG key issue that is encountered when using the imported Linux Mint DE repository, and is significantly simpler than the other viable solution. Also, this gives you access to Thunderbird and SeaMonkey as well.

Note that this solution only gives you the English-US Release Channel version (no beta or Aurora builds). Other languages can be used, but additional steps are required.
See the project page at [Ubuntuzilla](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ubuntuzilla/index.php?title=Main_Page) for more information.

Comment: Works like charm!

Comment: +1 for the `--keyserver` stuff! Actually iceweasel not needed to be removed. I was afraid that the settings and saved passwords would be lost, so I kept iceweasel.

Comment: +1 Thanks! @TrueY Iceweasel works even with FireFox installed? I had already uninstalled iceweasel and when I try to install it (in Kali 2.0,) I get an error that it clashes with firefox: `diversion of /usr/bin/firefox to /usr/bin/firefox.real by iceweasel' clashes with `diversion of /usr/bin/firefox to /usr/bin/firefox.ubuntu by firefox-mozilla-build` I wonder if I hadn't uninstalled it, if they would have played well together?

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie I think they cannot run parallel. I had a Firefox running and I tried to start Iceweasel and I got a message box with the following text: "Iceweasel is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Iceweasel process, or restart your system."

Comment: No longer works!

Answer (score 24):

[This](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=62113) post on the Debian User forums suggests the following:

- Download latest Firefox from: http://www.mozilla.com . If using wget, remember to escape any `&` with `\` so it doesn't break the url down into a series of background process
- Copy the downloaded file to `/opt`
- Extract it using:

  ```
  $ tar -jxvf firefox-x.x.xx.tar.bz2
  ```
- Change the permissions of the file:

  ```
  $ chown -R root:users /opt/firefox

  $ chmod 750 /opt/firefox
  ```

  Note that the user should be a group member of "users"

  ```
  $ usermod -a -G users username
  ```
- Create a symbolic link

  ```
  $ ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
  ```
- Delete `firefox-x.x.xx.tar.bz2` from `/opt`

To install new versions, you are supposed to

```
# rm -rf /opt/firefox*
# rm /usr/bin/firefox
```

To make a desktop icon, do this

```
$ touch /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

Edit this using your favourite text editor:

```
$ nano /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

Contents of `firefox.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Mozilla Firefox
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox %U
Icon=/opt/firefox/icons/mozicon128.png
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

You can remove iceweasel with

```
$ apt-get remove iceweasel
```

If you encounter this error:

```
./firefox: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

You should probably install

```
apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk
```

Chances are that you are trying to install the 32 bit version of firefox in a 64 bit Debian environment.

Comment: i did all the steps but i have no permission of open firefox. any ideas?

Comment: # ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox

ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/bin/firefox': File exists

Comment: Turns out debian put a shell script at /usr/bin/firefox that executes iceweasel. Dick move.

Comment: @miguel This post is very old, not sure how valid it is still

Comment: Two updates! First...
`ln -sf /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox # force the symlink`
...
The other is the icon path on the firefox.desktop is now in another location: `ls /opt/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png`

Answer (score 6):

Iceweasel Aurora is very close to Firefox latest stable release.

I installed **Iceweasel Aurora using [this official debian/mozilla tutorial](http://mozilla.debian.net/)**.

I was able to import my Firefox profile from another installation without errors, ie, all addons, bookmarks, history entries and user settings are working perfectly.

FYI, some of the plugins I use are Firebug, Awesome screenshot and Searchstatus, all worked fine and were not disabled by Iceweasel.

**You may also want to use the [Firefox logo](http://files.softicons.com/download/system-icons/oxygen-icons-by-oxygen/png/128x128/apps/firefox.png) for launchers.**

This is probably a better option as it allows an easier update process.

Answer (score 5):

No need for this any more. Debian stable started shipping Firefox instead of iceweasel today.

Debian will ship the Extended Support Release (ESR) of Firefox, which is roughly updated every 9 months.
If you always need the latest version the others answers may stil be an option for you.

For more infomarmation see the [debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=815006)

Answer (score 4):

For the Googlers... this works for Debian Jessie:

```
#Add GnuPG archive key for mozilla.debian.net repository to the list of trusted keys
wget -q -O - http://mozilla.debian.net/archive.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Depending on the version you want (pick one),

- Release version:

  ```
  cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla-firefox.list
  deb http://mozilla.debian.net/ jessie-backports firefox-release
  EOF
  ```
- Beta version:

  ```
  cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla-firefox.list
  deb http://mozilla.debian.net/ jessie-backports firefox-beta
  EOF
  ```
- Aurora version:

  ```
  cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla-firefox.list
  deb http://mozilla.debian.net/ jessie-backports firefox-aurora
  EOF
  ```

Then:

```
#Assign higher priority to recently added repository.    
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
Package: *
Pin: origin mozilla.debian.net
Pin-Priority: 501
EOF

apt-get update && apt-get install firefox
```

Source: https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2016/03/21/how-to-use-recent-version-of-firefox-in-debian-jessie/

Comment: Just FYI, Iceweasel wasn't renamed to Firefox, as premised in the link.  Iceweasel was a sanitized, rebranded version of Firefox.  The Iceweasel project was discontinued and now actual Firefox is what is distributed with Debian.  If Jessie still has Iceweasel ESR, that will be gone as soon as the ESR version is deprecated.  Debian stable (currently Jessie), will have Firefox ESR.  This has a major release roughly once/year, with security updates but not feature changes in between.  Debian Testing should already have standard, current-release Firefox

Comment: Cleanest way to get it right from the source.
+1 for the key

Answer (score 3):

This method is working for me on Debian 9 Stretch (64bit):

```
cd ~/Downloads

/usr/bin/curl -L -o firefox-latest-linux64.tar.bz2 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US" && sudo tar xvf firefox-latest-linux64.tar.bz2 -C /opt/ && rm firefox-latest-linux64.tar.bz2

sudo ln -sf /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

You can set something like this in your root's crontab for @daily or @weekly

The download link was derived from this Mozilla readme.txt: https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/latest/README.txt

Comment: Pretty straightforward

Comment: beautiful!  works from the command line with no customization.

Answer (score 2):

First edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to include:

> deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import

Update system repositories:

```
$ apt-get update
```

You may get and ignore a following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.linuxmint.com debian Release:
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public
key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3EE67F3D0FF405B2
```

Once system's repositories are updated simply use apt-get command to install Firefox Browser on your Debian Jessie 8 Linux:

```
$ apt-get install firefox

Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                             
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 40.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 89.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
firefox
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
```

Once the installation is finished you can start Firefox either from command line:

```
$ firefox
```

Comment: This is no longer necessary.  Iceweasel has been discontinued and Firefox is now what is provided by Debian.  Iceweasel ESR was associated with Debian Stable, and that will disappear when the old ESR version is deprecated shortly.  In the meantime, Firefox is available in Jessie via backport.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running an AMD Athlon II X2 system. Firefox runs perfectly on Wheezy i686 & the 3.2.0-4-686-pae kernel. The stock version of IceWeasel just seemed gutted, crippled and inferior compared to Firefox. Installation is a snap. I download the newest Firefox to /home/myusername/Linux/Software/Mozilla/current/, and then run

```
cd /opt
sudo rm -R firefox*
sudo cp /home/myusername/Linux/Software/Mozilla/current/firefox* /opt
sudo tar jxvf firefox*
```

The second line removes the previous version completely before the upgrade.

Comment: `sudo rm -R firefox*` seems quite dangerous, what if you had other firefox* folders in /opt?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the most straight forward method I've found for replacing Iceweasel with Firefox in Debian.

Wiki >>> [Ubuntuzilla: Mozilla Software Installer](https://sourceforge.net/p/ubuntuzilla/wiki/Main_Page/)

The terminal commands are as follows:

```
:~$ sudo apt remove iceweasel

:~$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following entry to the source.list file:

```
deb https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/ all main
```

Save and exit Nano.

```
:~$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29

:~$ sudo apt update

:~$ sudo apt install firefox-mozilla-build
```

I hope this will be of help to anyone else wanting to replace Iceweasel with the current version of Firefox. As far as I have seen, the source is very well documented and maintained.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of Manuel Garza's answer.

Comment: You're right. I found Ubuntuzilla as I was seeking an answer myself. I didn't see Manuel Garza's answer above, though I wish I had, as this would have saved me some time. Iceweasle isn't playing html5 video and this is how I fixed it. I love Debian, so actually switching to Ubuntu isn't an option. Thanks for the heads up as to being a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

$ sudo apt-get install firefox-esr

The -esr apparently means Extended Support Release.