# How to get flash on Firefox 11 in Debian Squeeze?

Tags: firefox, debian, flash, iceweasel

I have just started dabbling in Debian and I really love Firefox. I have Firefox installed, but I can't figure out how to get Flash in Firefox. All of the online guides I have tried lead to one dead end or another. Can anybody walk me through how to get Flash working in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Without having direct experience in the matter, doesn't Debian have a package manager which you can search for Flash and it will install it automatically?  I know the last time I forayed into playing with Ubuntu on my laptop I used the package manager to install flash and the problem was solved.  If nothing else I am sure you can simply take it to the console and do a dpkg -i (package).deb after downloading the .deb file...otherwise an apt-get should work if you could get the package name.  I will look into this for a bit to see if I find anything

Comment: Well, doing "sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree" just installs the player for iceweasel. It doesn't work for Firefox. There must be some way to link the files though, being that iceweasel is a Firefox spinoff.

Comment: In the meantime, try something like 'apt-cache search ^flash'

Comment: Ah, I forgot about Iceweasel...If it works for Iceweasel, why not just use it instead of FireFox?

If you are deadset on trying to use FireFox, maybe this would help? http://superuser.com/questions/322376/how-to-install-real-firefox-on-debian-6